# Modelling a system with multiple hysteresis behaviours and mutual interference

Tags: control-engineering, modeling

I'm trying to model a non-linear, static SISO system with

- input variable $u$
- disturbance variable $z$ (can be controlled for identification purposes but not during actual operation)
- output variable $x$
- system behaviour $N\{x,u,z\}$ is hysteresis afflicted for both $u$ and $z$
- $u$ and $z$ influence the hysteresis characteristics of each other

I'm searching for any literature that deals with this kind of problem. 
It should contain approaches on how to model such a system and if possible a way to invert it, because ultimately I'm trying to linearize the overall behaviour $N^{-1}\{N\} = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 possible approaches:

1. Mayergoyz describes in [chapter 2 of his book](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780124808737500037) "Mathematical Models of Hysteresis and Their Applications" a Preisach model of magnetostricitve material. He considers a system with two cross-coupled inputs, which suits the problem prefectly.
2. If the hysteresis of the disturbance value $z$ is negligible, one might try the [modified Prandtl-Ishlinksi](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.463.7198&rep=rep1&type=pdf) approach, in which the influence of $z$ on the $x$-$u$ hysteresis is modelled by an unambiguous characteristic. Furthermore this approach is highly suited for compensation purposes, since the model can be analytically inverted.